# OpenSSL compilation fails

Tags: software-installation, compiling, openssl

I try to compile the latest version but I get this error message.

```
$ make OPENSSL=/usr/local/ssl
Makefile:82: ../aolserver/include/Makefile.module: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '../aolserver/include/Makefile.module'.  Stop.
```

What should I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method to compile the latest LTS version of OpenSSL could be something like the following set of commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
mkdir $HOME/openssl_build && cd $HOME/openssl_build
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz
tar xvf openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz && cd openssl-1.0.2l
./config --prefix=/opt && make 
sudo make install
```

This gives the following result on my own system:

```
andrew@ilium:~$ /opt/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
andrew@ilium:~$
```

The installation to `/opt` will mean that there will be no clash with the system OpenSSL. As this is *not* integrated with the Ubuntu package management system the following *one liner* will need to be used to fully remove this installation:

```
sudo rm -rfv /opt/ssl /opt/include/openssl /opt/lib/engines \
             /opt/bin/{c_rehash,openssl} \
             /opt/lib/{libcrypto.a,libssl.a} \
             /opt/lib/pkgconfig/{libcrypto.pc,libssl.pc,openssl.pc}
```

Ready for your next upgraded or downgraded version of OpenSSL :).