# openssl installation - `/bin/` directory missing

Tags: 17.04, openssl

I was following [this guide on how to install OpenSSL](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-and-update-openssl-on-ubuntu-16-04/)

---

It worked when I tried it on a VM (running ubuntu). But while executing on my actual machine, I noticed, my `/bin/` folder is missing.

```
root@akki-X555LAB:/usr/local/ssl# ls
certs  misc  openssl.cnf  openssl.cnf.dist  private
```

---

The command I was trying to execute was:

```
ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
```

I was simply following the commands in that link and don't understand what went wrong!
For reference:

```
root@akki-X555LAB:/usr/local/ssl# openssl version
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If missing, you need to create "my bin folder", for example, `mkdir /usr/local/ssl/bin`.

Comment: Perhaps a re-install would surfic?

Comment: Is the information in this question and answer any help: https://askubuntu.com/q/941780/57576 ?

Comment: @George yeah..i did a fresh install and it worked out smoothly..