# Can't install Openssl on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, openssl

I can't install openssl in Ubuntu 18.04.
I followed the steps below:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1b.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /opt/openssl 
sudo tar xfvz ~/Downloads/openssl-1.1.1b.tar.gz --directory /opt/openssl
perl --version
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
cd /opt/openssl/openssl-1.1.1b
sudo ./config –prefix=/opt/openssl –openssldir=/opt/openssl/ssl
```

All the steps return positive messages, except the last one, that returns the following:

```
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2

Failure!  build file wasn't produced.
Please read INSTALL and associated NOTES files.  You may also have to look over
your available compiler tool chain or change your configuration.

target already defined - linux-x86_64 (offending arg: –prefix=/opt/openssl)
```

If anyone can help, I would appreciate.

Comment: Is this answer any use to you: https://askubuntu.com/a/941794/57576 With appropriate  adjustments to the source names...

Comment: I tried all the steps, but I got the following error:
/opt/bin/openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /opt/bin/openssl)
/opt/bin/openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0i' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1)
/opt/bin/openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1)

Comment: Why do you want to install OpenSSL from sources?

Comment: The arguments to config are "--prefix" and "--openssldir". The double minus signs are significant

Comment: @vidarlo I tried any other way, and I seem to get an error message with every application that requires it.

Comment: @MattCaswell, thanks, that really helped. I got the message:
`OpenSSL has been successfully configured`. However, when I try to check version, I still get the error `openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by openssl)`

Comment: @DaniloSteckelberg you've tried building applications that require openssl, but failed? Generally I would try to resolve that problem, and not install openssl from sources.

Comment: @DaniloSteckelberg Read the file NOTES.UNIX in the openssl source distribution. In particular the section "Shared libraries and installation in non-default locations"

Answer (score 1):

For me if I use --prefix instead of -prefix it works fine, I had the same problem earlier notice the following:

> ./config –prefix=/opt/OpenSSL –openssldir=/opt/OpenSSL Operating
>   system: x86_64-whatever-linux2

```
Failure!  build file wasn't produced.
Please read INSTALL and associated NOTES files.  You may also have to look over
your available compiler tool chain or change your configuration.

target already defined - linux-x86_64 (offending arg: –prefix=/opt/OpenSSL)
```

However, using:

> ./config -–prefix=/opt/OpenSSL/ -–openssldir=/opt/OpenSSL/

It works fine and produces:

```
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1c (0x1010103fL) for linux-x86_64
Using os-specific seed configuration
Creating configdata.pm
Creating Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
```

I hope this helps